# How to physically/logically separate integration layer and data warehouse and is that necessary?

Tags: database, schema, etl, data-warehouse, vertica

On our testing DWH server, we're using Vertica Community Edition. We're very pleased with ETL process and queries performance.

We import data from few sources (Informix, SQL Server, MySQL, Google Docs) putting it in one schema, with prefix ***bussinessProcessName_stage_***

At the end of ETL process there is many tables called ***bussinessProcessName_fact*** and ***bussinessProcessName_dim_dimName*** and few ***shared_dim_dimName***.

Is there a need for separating those tables in different schema, or maybe different database?
The same question is for data marts inside DWH.

We're using star-schema mostly, show-flake few times, and there is even one flat-table designed data mart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most database systems use the database level as the highest logical hierarchy. However, Vertica only allows a single database to be running at a single time. This means that the logical design takes place at the schema level. For example, a traditional database system may have databases such as `customers` and `orders`. In Vertica, these would be identified at the schema level.

The logical organization and naming convention varies between organizations. What matters is that it's standard and used consistently. You may want to look at what logically fits together, and group tables accordingly. For example, each business process name can have its own schema (`business_process_name.fact_table`). It's better practice to be explicit rather than using a single schema, even if you have few tables. If in the future you add additional tables, it'll be easier to manage.

Another benefit of using schemas would be for administration. When performing backups, or maintenance tasks, they can be performed at the schema level.

Comment: Didn't know about single db at time in Vertica. So, for better data management you think I should separate data marts in different schemas. What's about staging layer? Would you separate each staging data in different schema or put it all in one? Or it's more organisational question rather then techniqal?

Comment: I don't see why staging data shouldn't remain in the same schema as the target table. As long as these tables are identifiable as staging, whether in the name of the table, or if they exist as `TEMPORARY` tables.